# How to improve spacing in a document when adding data in key value pair using google docs API and python

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-docs-api, google-api-python-client, google-developers-console

How should I modify my request payload to add data as key value pair in a google docx using google docs API in python.

When I use the following payload, the alignment gets ruined.

```
requests = [{
   "insertText":{
      "text":"\nName of the Organization\t\t\t\tStackOverflow\nIndustry\t\t\t\tSo
ftware\nBusiness_Id\t\t\t123\n",
      "location":{
         "index":4
      }
   }
}]
```

Output:
[image]

How can I align it properly so that the output is something like

```
Name Of the Organization        StackOverflow
Industry                        Software
Business_Id                     123
```

or can we put this in a table without showing the table borders?

Comment: Is the use of a table included in your goal?

Comment: @Tanaike putting the contents in a table is not my goal but if we put in a table, then can we hide the table/cell borders?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that the table and cell borders can be removed. But I deeply apologize that I couldn't notice that your goal didn't include the use of the table.

Comment: @Tanaike I think they are saying that if the table borders can be removed, then yes, the solution can be realised with a table.

Comment: yes, If we can make the table borders invisible then it would be an accepted solution

Comment: @I hope this is helpful to you Thank you for your always support. I had thought that OP doesn't want to achieve the goal using a table. But from your comment, I could understand that the use of a table was included in the OP's goal. So, I proposed an answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Ask_Ashu Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your replying, I could understand that the use of a table was included in your goal. So, I proposed an answer using a table. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your situation, I would like to propose using a table for achieving your goal. When Docs API is used, the table can be created without borders. But unfortunately, in the current stage, I had thought that it is difficult to directly create a table using Docs API. So I had created a library for managing the table on Google Document using Docs API. In this answer, I would like to propose to achieve your goal using this library.

### Usage:

#### 1. Install library.

```
$ pip install gdoctableapppy
```

#### 2. Sample script:

```py
docs = build('docs', 'v1', credentials=creds) # Please use your script here.
documentId = "###" # Please set Google Document ID.

values = [['Name Of the Organization', 'StackOverflow'], ['Industry', 'Software'], ['Business_Id', '123']]
resource = {
    "oauth2": creds,
    "documentId": documentId,
    "rows": len(values),
    "columns": len(values[0]),
    "append": True,
    "values": values,
}
gdoctableapp.CreateTable(resource)
resource = {
    "oauth2": creds,
    "documentId": documentId,
}
res = gdoctableapp.GetTables(resource)
obj = {"color": {"color": {}}, "dashStyle": "SOLID", "width": {"magnitude": 0, "unit": "PT"}}
requests = [{
    "updateTableCellStyle": {
        "tableCellStyle": {
            "borderBottom": obj,
            "borderTop": obj,
            "borderLeft": obj,
            "borderRight": obj,
        },
        "tableStartLocation": {
            "index": res['tables'][-1]['tablePosition']['startIndex']
        },
        "fields": "borderBottom,borderTop,borderLeft,borderRight"
    }
}]
docs.documents().batchUpdate(documentId=documentId, body={'requests': requests}).execute()
```

#### 3. Testing.

When the above script is run, the following result can be obtained.

[image]

### References:

- [gdoctableapppy](https://pypi.org/project/gdoctableapppy/)

  - This is a python library to manage the tables on Google Document using Google Docs API.
- [Method: documents.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate)

Comment: Really thorough answer man. I did not realize you could get rid of the borders like that. Thanks!

Comment: @josephvictory Thank you for your comment. When my answer will be useful for you, I'm glad. Thank you, too.

Comment: @Tanaike, Thank you for this solution. I never knew this is something doable. It works when I run this script separately but when I combine this request payload with other requests, it throws an error `"Invalid requests[1].updateTableCellStyle: The provided table start location is invalid.". Details: "Invalid requests[1].up
dateTableCellStyle: The provided table start location is invalid.">` I guess start index of the table needs to be managed as I would be having multiple tables in my document.

Comment: @Ask_Ashu Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `but when I combine this request payload with other requests, it throws an error`. When I tested my proposed script, no error occurs. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. In order to correctly understand your current situation, can you provide detailed information to correctly replicate your situation? By this, I would like to confirm it. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.

Comment: @Tanaike Please don't apologize, you helped me a lot during this document creation. I'll update the question to replicate the error which I'm getting.

Comment: @Tanaike, I've updated the question with the code I'm using in my local

Comment: Sure, I'll close this and ask a new question