# How to align table in a google document using google docx API and Python

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-docs-api, google-api-python-client, google-developers-console

I've got solution to add table without border [suggested by Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70471393/invalid-table-start-location-error-while-using-gdoctableapp-module-to-create-tab/70472878?noredirect=1#comment124608948_70472878) but I'm still facing issues in indexing.
I want to insert data in the document in the following order (function - `insert_data(file_id)`) -

- Insert an image in a document (Index = 1)
- Insert text in a document (index = 2)
- Insert table in a document having invisible borders (index = 3)
- Insert text in the document (index = 4)
- Insert table in a document again having invisible borders (index = 5)
- Insert new line (index = 6)
- Insert image in a document (index = 7)

The code I'm trying is-

```
import io
from gdoctableapppy import gdoctableapp

SERVICE_FILENAME = 'C:/Users/XYZ/Testpython/service_account.json'  # set path to service account filename

from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload, MediaFileUpload

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_FILENAME,
                                                                    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
                                                                            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents']
                                                                    )
docs = build('docs', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
drive = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)


def create_file(file_name):
    file_metadata = {
        "title": file_name,
        "body": {}
    }

    file = docs.documents().create(body=file_metadata).execute()
    print('File ID: %s' % file.get('documentId'))
    file_id = file.get('documentId')
    try:
        permission = {
            "role": "writer",
            "type": "user",
            'emailAddress': 'xyz@gmail.com'
        }
        result = drive.permissions().create(fileId=file_id, body=permission).execute()
        print(result)
        return file_id
    except Exception as e:
        print('An error occurred:', e)
    return None


def insert_data(file_id):
    requests = []
    values = [['Name of the Client/Organization', 'XYZ'], ['Industry', 'Software']]
    requests.append(insert_table_data(file_id, values, index=3))
    values2 = [['Country', 'India'], ['State', 'UP']]
    requests.append(insert_table_data(file_id, values2, index=5))
    requests.append(insert_image(index=1))
    requests.append(insert_text(2, '\ntext\n'))
    requests.append(insert_text(4, '\nDemo text\n'))
    requests.append(insert_text(6, '\n'))
    requests.append(insert_image(index=7))


    result = docs.documents().batchUpdate(documentId=file_id, body={'requests': requests}).execute()


def insert_image(index):
    image_data = {
        'insertInlineImage': {
            'location': {
                'index': index
            },
            'uri':
                'https://www.oberlo.com/media/1603970279-pexels-photo-3.jpg?fit=max&fm=jpg&w=1824',
            'objectSize': {
                'height': {
                    'magnitude': 350,
                    'unit': 'PT'
                },
                'width': {
                    'magnitude': 350,
                    'unit': 'PT'
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return image_data


def insert_text(index, text):
    text_data = {
        "insertText":
            {
                "text": text,
                "location":
                    {
                        "index": index
                    }
            }
    }

    return text_data


def insert_table_data(file_id, values, index):
    documentId = file_id
    resource = {
        "oauth2": credentials,
        "documentId": documentId,
        "rows": len(values),
        "columns": len(values[0]),
        # "append": True,
        "createIndex": index,
        "values": values,
    }
    gdoctableapp.CreateTable(resource)
    resource = {
        "oauth2": credentials,
        "documentId": documentId,
    }
    res = gdoctableapp.GetTables(resource)
    obj = {"color": {"color": {}}, "dashStyle": "SOLID", "width": {"magnitude": 0, "unit": "PT"}}
    data = {
        "updateTableCellStyle": {
            "tableCellStyle": {
                "borderBottom": obj,
                "borderTop": obj,
                "borderLeft": obj,
                "borderRight": obj,
            },
            "tableStartLocation": {
                "index": res['tables'][-1]['tablePosition']['startIndex']
            },
            "fields": "borderBottom,borderTop,borderLeft,borderRight"
        }
    }
    # docs.documents().batchUpdate(documentId=documentId, body={'requests': requests}).execute()
    return data


def download_as_docx(file_id):
    results = drive.files().get(fileId=file_id, fields="id, name, mimeType, createdTime").execute()
    docMimeType = results['mimeType']
    mimeTypeMatchup = {
        "application/vnd.google-apps.document": {
            "exportType": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", "docExt": "docx"
        }
    }
    exportMimeType = mimeTypeMatchup[docMimeType]['exportType']
    # docExt = mimeTypeMatchup[docMimeType]['docExt']
    docName = results['name']
    request = drive.files().export_media(fileId=file_id,
                                         mimeType=exportMimeType)  # Export formats : https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-export-formats
    # fh = io.FileIO(docName + "." + docExt, mode='w')
    fh = io.FileIO(docName, mode='w')
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
    done = False
    while done is False:
        status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
        print("Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))


def download_as_pdf(file_id, file_name):
    request = drive.files().export_media(fileId=file_id,
                                         mimeType='application/pdf')
    fh = io.BytesIO()
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
    done = False
    while done is False:
        status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
        print("Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))
    fh.seek(0)
    filename = file_name.split('.docx')[0] + '.pdf'
    with open(filename, 'wb') as fx:
        fx.write(fh.getvalue())


def delete_gdrive_file(file_id):
    """Deleted file on Google Drive
    :param file_id: ID of Google Drive file
    """
    response = drive.files().delete(fileId=file_id).execute()
    print(response)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_name = 'Data.docx'
    file_id = create_file(file_name)
    insert_data(file_id)
    download_as_docx(file_id)
    download_as_pdf(file_id, file_name)
    delete_gdrive_file(file_id)
```

Error:

```
returned "Invalid requests[0].insertTable: Index 4 must be less than the end index of the referenced segment, 2.". Details: "Invalid requests[0].insertTable: Index 4 
must be less than the end index of the referenced segment, 2.">
```

I guess end index of the table goes to 67 but even if I try to insert new data at index 68, it either appends in the last cell of the table or it throws indexing error sometimes.
I should I make the whole data insertion flow dynamic in the google docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- The library gdoctableapp creates the table by one call. By this, when you request the flow of your question, the index is changed for the tables. I thought that this is the reason of your issue.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Please modify `insert_table_data` as follows.

```py
def insert_table_data(file_id, values, index):
    documentId = file_id
    resource = {
        "oauth2": credentials,
        "documentId": documentId,
        "rows": len(values),
        "columns": len(values[0]),
        # "append": True,
        "createIndex": index,
        "values": values,
    }
    gdoctableapp.CreateTable(resource)
```

And also, please modify `insert_data` as follows.

```py
def insert_data(file_id):
    # Insert texts and images.
    index = 1
    requests = []
    requests.append(insert_image(index))
    index += 1
    text1 = '\ntext\n'
    requests.append(insert_text(index, text1))
    index += len(text1)
    table1 = index
    text2 = '\nDemo text\n'
    requests.append(insert_text(index, text2))
    index += len(text2)
    table2 = index
    text3 = '\n'
    requests.append(insert_text(index, text3))
    index += len(text3)
    requests.append(insert_image(index))
    docs.documents().batchUpdate(documentId=file_id, body={'requests': requests}).execute()

    # Create tables.
    values2 = [['Country', 'India'], ['State', 'UP']]
    insert_table_data(file_id, values2, table2)
    values1 = [['Name of the Client/Organization', 'XYZ'], ['Industry', 'Software']]
    insert_table_data(file_id, values1, table1)

    # Remove borders of tables.
    resource = {"oauth2": credentials, "documentId": file_id}
    res = gdoctableapp.GetTables(resource)
    obj = {"color": {"color": {}}, "dashStyle": "SOLID", "width": {"magnitude": 0, "unit": "PT"}}
    reqs = []
    for e in res['tables']:
        data = {
            "updateTableCellStyle": {
                "tableCellStyle": {
                    "borderBottom": obj,
                    "borderTop": obj,
                    "borderLeft": obj,
                    "borderRight": obj,
                },
                "tableStartLocation": {
                    "index": e['tablePosition']['startIndex']
                },
                "fields": "borderBottom,borderTop,borderLeft,borderRight"
            }
        }
        reqs.append(data)
    docs.documents().batchUpdate(documentId=file_id, body={'requests': reqs}).execute()
```

- In this modification, I separate the texts and images, and the tables. By this, the index of tables can be correctly retrieved.

#### Note:

- This modified script is for your question. So when your actual situation is different from your question, this modified script might not be able to be directly used. So please be careful about this.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation @Tanaike. I modified the script as per my  requirement and the table is getting added wherever I want.

Comment: @Ask_Ashu Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.